# Policy or guidelines on accepting a different answer

Tags: discussion, accepting

Two years ago I asked a [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17780/deeper-levels-of-subsections-dont-appear-in-the-latex-output-of-pandoc-why), which, in short, got the answer "not possible, try different route".

This was a solution and I accepted that. Now a technical solution comes along and someone answers with that.

Can I un-accept the original accepted answer and accept the new answer? And if so, should I best edit my post to reflect that?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The accepted answer is the one of 'most use to the original questioner'. As such, it is really down to you which one you take: it's quite reasonable to move the tick. You might of course want to explain why, for example in a comment on the answer you 'unaccept'.

It's worth noting that the fact that the tick is down to the questioner alone means that it's perfectly possible for others to view a different solution as 'better'. However, that's what voting is for, and the two concepts are not identical.

Answer (score 5):

Well, in general, we consider questions that are solved by a new version of a package to be off-topic. So theoretically, the question should be closed ;)

However, I would say that it should stay open and changing the tick looks like a reasonable idea :)

Comment: I thought it was more that things have been considered off-topic if they were asked when the 'release' version of the same package _already_ fixed the issue.

Comment: I will sometimes post a new answer to a long-ago answered/accepted question, if new technology (i.e., packages) provide an alternate, perhaps preferable, way to achieve the result.  I'm not trying to get the questioner to change their accepted answer.  Rather, I'm thinking of the person using the search feature who is likely to stumble across that question, based on his keywords.

Comment: @JosephWright That's a good point probably. The question is: how much does that make a difference _now_ whether the question was posted 2 _days_ ago or 2 _years_ ago. Probably the common sense here is that it makes a difference, in general we seem not to close questions as "out-dated", right?